# PL/SQL code to update a table with an If statement

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a drop down list where the user can select various action types.

Sample: (:P6_Action_ind)

```
Full Acceptance

Partial Acceptance

Decline/Default
```

If user selects Full Acceptance I want to update (Accept_shares) column on ca_offer table with the original offer amount from (offer_shares) column.

I am trying to do this on a process point (On Submit)

```
  if :P6_ACTION_IND = 'FULL ACCEPTANCE' then
  update ca_offer
    set accept_shares = offer_shares
    where seq_id = :P6_SEQ_ID;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of the select list item vs the descriptive text. This value is what's set in session state and should be used as the literal string in your code.

An LOV will display a value, and store a different value - hence two columns in the select statement. You need to ensure the second column, the stored value, is in session state (button on developer toolbar at bottom of runtime), and matches whatever you've hardcoded in the PL/SQL.

Comment: Makes sense will need to figure out how to code that as that value comes from another table.

Comment: here is the code I use for the pop up {select OFFER_ACTION_DESC d, OFFER_ACTION_DESC r
  from CA_OFFER_ACTION
WHERE OFFER_NAME = :P6_OFFER_TYPE}

Comment: Hi Scott so I checked an the field had not value so I will need to incorporate something from that other table where I do get the values. But I am still very new to PL/SQL not sure how I can call the same data I used to create the POV into the Update

Comment: Perhaps you should install the APEX Sample Application and explore how they've solved problems.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried update ca_offer a set (accept_shares) = (SELECT A.OFFER_SHARES from >CA_OFFER A, CA_OFFER_ACTION B where B.OFFER_ACTION_DESC = 'FULL ACCEPTANVCE'); >but that didn't work..

You probably tried to get the column offer_shares from table ca_offer corresponding to the 'FULL ACCEPTANCE'.

You made a typo in ACCEPTANVCE,
and the update should get the value for accept_shares via a subquery returning one row and one column from the lookup table.

```
update ca_offer 
set accept_shares = (
   select offer_shares
   from ca_offer_action
   where OFFER_ACTION_DESC = 'FULL ACCEPTANCE'
)
where seq_id = :P6_SEQ_ID
```

See Subquery3 in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm)

But then again, you should have selected the reference field in the LOV in the R field in the first place (D=Description, R=Reference)

```
Select OFFER_ACTION_DESC D, offer_shares R 
FROM CA_OFFER_ACTION 
WHERE OFFER_NAME = :P6_OFFER_TYPE
```

Comment: Hi D, the issue with that is that OFFER_ACTION_DESC is on a different table then OFFER_SHARES. and yes I did see the typo and fix it but still no could get the table to update.

Comment: I seem to have some other issue as I wanted to check if the update statement even would trigger.. and that is a big NOPE. now I didn't build this app and it is using (DML) will that effect my pl/sql update after submit?